# Background color problems

Tags: html, css

I have a container that is 960px wide and floats on top of the main body.

I want the body to be grey and the container to be white.

As you can picture it, the sides will be grey.

For some reason, when I set these colours, the grey is in the container too!

Can someone take a look at my code and see if you can spot where I'm going wrong?

CSS

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    color:#333333;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color:grey;
}

#container{
    width:960px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:white;
    padding:0 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>  
    <div id="container">
        
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, your container has no content or specified height.

Comment: Your code works fine - you need to have some content in the `div` for it to show up, or otherwise set the height. See http://jsfiddle.net/BKFKK/

Comment: I removed all the code from within the container div so the question wasn't cluttered!

Comment: If you do have content in the div, the error may be in there. Can you post a link to your real site? Also, the font size in the body will be about 90% of the user's preferred size; is that by design?

Comment: Does your content use any floats? If so, you might have forgotten to 'clear it'. "clear:both;" in an element after the floated elements, or "overflow:auto;" on #container would fix it. Or did you use "position:absolute;"? That takes the element out of the 'flow', which could also explain it. Try using border:1px solid #color on #container to see what's ailing.

Answer (score 1):

Define `height` to your `#coantainer` or write something inside of your it. Right now the `height` of the container `DIV` is `zero`

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/VxWFz/

Comment: Even with the content I have, the height property is what makes it work. Is there a way to dynamically have height for what's needed?

Comment: @Luke Does the div have an overflow property set somewhere? With the default settings, it should adjust its height to its content.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add dimension to the html, body selector:

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    color:#333333;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color:grey;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Otherwise the body is just the same width as your container div and will rest on its sides... So to speak.

Also add some content or an actual height to the container div to see it working. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have no ***content*** in your containder div.
Either put some content in it or give it some `height`.

#### [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/eqejuv/)

Answer (score 0):

Assign the height to "#container" or fill the #container div with some content. Otherwise change the background color - Grey.

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    color:#333333;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color:red;
}

#container{
    width:960px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:white;
    padding:0 5px;
}
```

Hello World!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <style type="text/css">
  html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    background:#FFF;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color:grey;
}

#container{
    width:960px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:0 5px;
}

  </style>

    <div id="container">
    urpis, sagittis ut vut ut augue diam est ac augue, adipiscing dolor. Auctor ut nunc dolor amet sagittis a quis ac, massa nec in? Egestas magnis in tempor. Porttitor pulvinar tincidunt aliquet eu auctor elementum augue, in pellentesque ac pulvinar tempor augue, tempor nisi vut eros.
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't get a height on the container ...
can you try this - it's is displaying fine for me :

```html
<html>
   <style>
      html, body
      {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      font-size: 0.95em;
      color:#333333;
      font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
      background-color:grey;
      }
      #container{
      width:960px;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      background-color:white;
      padding:0 5px;
      }
   </style>
   <body>
      <div id="container">
         test
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

which browser are you trying it on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead of your code

```
#container{
    width:960px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:white !important;
    padding:0 5px;
}
```